# getting file name from for %%i variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, cmd

I had a script that converts all mkvs in a folder to mp4s using `ffmpeg`. The downside is that it left the .mkv extension and just added .mp4 (eg: `file.mkv.mkp4`). I know `%~n` can be used to get a name without the extension, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my original script:

```
for %%i IN (*.mkv) DO (ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:00 -threads 6 -i "%%i" -vcodec copy -f mp4 -strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 128k -ac 2 "%%i.mp4")
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
for %%i IN (*.mkv) DO (ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:00 -threads 6 -i "%~ni.mkv" -vcodec copy -f mp4 -strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 128k -ac 2 "%~ni.mp4")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Percent signs of loop variables must be doubled in batch scripts, so you have to use `%%~ni` instead of `%~ni`. See the *Examples* section in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).

Comment: That link is dead, the proper location is: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490869.aspx

Comment: @MarcusJ Actually it's technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx, but thanks for the heads-up. Fixed.